# Make it easier to distinguish accepted and declined flags in addition to pending ones in flags history

Tags: feature-request, design, flag-history

[Originally posted on Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19184/feature-improvement-for-flags-history), but encouraged by others to post it here, saying that this is a solid idea but it might go unnoticed on Ask Ubuntu's Meta site. Posted as it is from Ask Ubuntu Meta.

In the flag summary section on a person's profile, it is difficult to differentiate the action of a flag. Although there is a feature to sort the flags' actions, it would be convenient to see them together. Just as the flags to be reviewed are highlighted with a bold orange background, it would be better to see a green background for the accepted flags and a red background for rejected flags.

[image: different flag types highlighted in flag summary]

In the given image above just as the `pending` flag is in the given orange background, the `helpful` flag could have a green background, and the self-removed could have a gray background.

I edited the CSS and HTML files to show how it could look if implemented.

[image: "helpful" highlighted green in flag summary]

Comment: I would make the pending flags yellow rather than orange. But the specific colours aside, I like the idea of colour coding in general.

Comment: The reason for only showing "pending" as highlighted appears to be historical. Originally, pending flags would not show *any* text next to them; only the flag and timestamp would show, with no status mark. It wasn't until later that the system began showing a status for them (originally "active", later renamed "pending") and the team didn't touch other parts of the system.

Comment: @JasonBassford I think the orange color is used only because it is native to Ask Ubuntu site. As SonictheMaskedWarehog said, only the pending was given color, so they decided to go with the native color of the site.

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog what are the chances of this feature being implemented.